# Update DLLs in the Program Files (x86) Folder

Tags: c#, windows, dll, installation

We have written a windows application.  It includes a start up bootstrapper.

The purpose of the bootstrapper is to check a list of files held on a server against what is installed in the programs installation folder, and update as needed.

The requirements forced on us by the client are :

The application must be installed in Program Files (x86) - rules out click once.
The application must check for updates on start up.

Now the bootstrapper code works fine when not using the program files directory, so it isn't a code issue.

How do I get admin privileges on the bootstrapper code so that it can write dll files into the program directory to make the updates work.  This has to work on windows 7/8/8.1/10.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add **Application Manifest File** to your project and replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This way your application will require administrator rights to run.

But better yet, consider following approach. Install launcher into **Program Files** and use it to download the latest version (of application or launcher) to the **AppData** folder and launch it from there - no admin rights required.

Comment: Would that allow the uninstall option to still work?

Comment: Also, is the the users AppData folder.  The application needs to run for all users who log onto the computer (oh the joys of shared enviroments)

Comment: Uninstall will work the same way as before - it will uninstall everything from Program Files. To remove files from AppData, you will need to implement it separately in installer.

Comment: Every user account have it's own AppData folder. Use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to get path of this folder and it will work for all users.

Comment: Thanks for this Anton.  It works well.  There is a down side.  With multiple users we effectively end up with multiple copies of the software, but I think we can live with that.